# Cannot get IIS7 and .NET 3.5 to allow urls containing colons

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, iis-7

We are currently transitioning from php (apache) to a MVC web site on IIS 7. We have a large number of legacy urls to support (to keep google happy) which contain what IIS 7 considers to be invalid characters specifically `:` and `&`.

We have applied the standard fix blanket fix to allow these special characters through i.e.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET]
"VerificationCompatibility"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters]
"AllowRestrictedChars"=dword:00000001
```

and although we can now get `&` to work the colon will fail with the following error

```
[NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.]
System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +868         
System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +9
```

It looks like all of this is catered for in .NET 4.0 but we need to release against 3.5 for now.

Has anyone got support for urls containing colons working on Iis 7 and .NET 3.5 ?

Comment: The error sounds like something thrown when accessing the filesystem. using the default MapPathBasedVirtualPathProvider. Have you tried building your own VirtualPathProvider?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a URL? Sounds like it would violate the standards.

Comment: I believe it does violate the standards however we must support it as its already out in the user community and more importantly google - an example would be be /travel/useful-information/london:dos-and-dont.html

Comment: Not tried anything as drastic as our own VirtualPathProvider but i'll certainly give it a google